# Arrow function use that is assigned by a module.export object cannot correctly resolve this

Tags: node.js, this, arrow-functions

It seems that only if I fill out the child object directly in the Base function that is the only way that the getSettings function can see the this.name property correctly, but I was trying to have my objects in different files to avoid having one large file.

```
***child.js***
module.exports : {
  getSettings: ()=>{
    return this.name === 'foobar'
  }
}

***base.js***
var Child = require('./child.js')
function Base(){
  this.name = 'foobar'
  this.child = Child
  this.child2 = {}
  for (var prop in Child){
    this.child2[prop] = Child[prop]
  }
  this.child3 = {
    getSettings: ()=>{
      return this.name === 'foobar'
    }
  }
}

***index.js****
var Base = require('./base.js')

var b = new Base()
b.child.getSettings() //FAILS BECAUSE this.name is undefined
b.child2.getSettings() //FAILS BECAUSE this.name is undefined
b.child3.getSettings() //PASSES. this.name is defined
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain proper example. `getSettings: {
    return this.name === 'foobar'
  }` syntax is wrong, it's unclear what's your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's conventional in JS OOP to refer class instance as `this`, so it's semantically incorrect for `child` objects to refer to parent object as `this`. This also makes it difficult to work with an object like `child` that doesn't get desirable context as lexical `this` (like `child3` does).

`child` object likely should be a class that are injected with parent instance as a dependency.

```
module.exports = class Child(parent) {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  getSettings() {
    return this.parent.name === 'foobar'
  }
}
```

---

```
var Child = require('./child.js')
function Base(){
  this.name = 'foobar'
  this.child = new Child(this);
  ...
}
```